# Problems with getting list of locations of Azure in Golang SDK

Tags: azure, go, azure-sdk

Why I receiving "nil" when doing request on getting of list locations of Azure?

Example :

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "errors"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2016-06-01/subscriptions"
)

func GetLocations(sess *AzureSession) (subscriptions.LocationListResult, error) {

    var locationsList subscriptions.LocationListResult

    client := subscriptions.NewClient()
    client.Authorizer = sess.Authorizer
    if locationsList, err := client.ListLocations(context.Background(), sess.SubscriptionID) ; err != nil {
        return locationsList, errors.New("Got error while traverising Azure locations")
    }

    fmt.Println(locationsList)

    return locationsList, nil
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why I have a response :

```
{{<nil>} <nil>}
```

Or how on other way I can get this list?

Comment: You're using `:=` which shadows `locationsList`. Remove the `:` so it assigns to your declared variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the short variable declaration `:=` within your error if block. This operator will automatically detect the type of your variable. So you don't need to implicitly type it. See the golang tour section https://tour.golang.org/basics/10

### Solution remove implicit variable declaration

```golang
...
func GetLocations(sess *AzureSession) (subscriptions.LocationListResult, error) {
    client := subscriptions.NewClient()
    client.Authorizer = sess.Authorizer
    if locationsList, err := client.ListLocations(context.Background(), sess.SubscriptionID) ; err != nil {
        return locationsList, errors.New("Got error while traverising Azure locations")
    }

    fmt.Println(locationsList)

    return locationsList, nil
}
```

### Solution remove the short declaration operator

If you really want to make it clear which type the var is use this snippet.

```golang
...
func GetLocations(sess *AzureSession) (subscriptions.LocationListResult, error) {

    var locationsList subscriptions.LocationListResult
    var err error

    client := subscriptions.NewClient()
    client.Authorizer = sess.Authorizer
    if locationsList, err = client.ListLocations(context.Background(), sess.SubscriptionID) ; err != nil {
        return locationsList, errors.New("Got error while traverising Azure locations")
    }

    fmt.Println(locationsList)

    return locationsList, nil
}
```

It is important that you can't mix short declaration with implicit declaration. So you need to also declare the `err` variable implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a pointer of locations, so you should use location pointer while iterating the location.value then it will work.
try the below format while iterating

```
for _, location := range *locationsList.Value {
            listOfRegions = append(listOfRegions, *location.Name)
        }
```